# What does setjmp call do in this example

Tags: c

I am trying to understand **setjmp** in the following code:

http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/YuvToJpegEncoder.cpp#24

What does this line setjpg() mean?

```
32   if (setjmp(sk_err.fJmpBuf)) {
33        return false;
34    }
```

Comment: What part of the manual page for `setjmp` didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setjmp` saves the context for a future call to `longjmp`. It returns zero when it is directly called (so, here, execution continues with `jpeg_create_compress`). When `longjmp` is called later (it must be before the current function returns, but it can be at any arbitrary call depth), execution will directly return to the `setjmp` call, and resume as if `setjmp` returned whatever you gave to `longjmp`. Presumably, in this case, `longjmp` will be called with a non-zero value, hence the method will directly return `false`.

Looking at the context, it looks like it is used for error handling. I assume `longjmp` can be called during the following `compress`. Think of it like low-level exceptions.

Comment: I first encountered it during a C course, where they advised using signals and `longjmp` as a sort of exception mechanism; and you could also recover from things like `SIGFPE` and `SIGINT`. However, it later turned out that C standard says it's undefined behaviour to `longjmp` out of a signal handler.

Answer (score 3):

`setjmp` establishes a return-point that you can return to from deep in the call stack using `longjmp`. It's usually considered bad style (akin to `goto`).

The first time it is called, it returns 0. Then if a `longjmp` happens back to the jump-point, it will be *as if* `setjmp` returned with 1. `longjmp` can also send a different return code, but if you try to send 0, the result will be 1.

```
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf j;

main(){
    if(setjmp(j)){
        printf("boo!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    myfunc();
    printf("5");
}

myfunc(){
    printf("1");
    myotherfunc();
}

myotherfunc(){
    printf("2");
    myfriendsfunc();
}

myfriendsfunc(){
    printf("3");
    longjmp(j, 0);
    printf("4");
}
```

output:

```
$ ./jmp
123boo!
```